# Minting a token in wallets on daily basis

Tags: erc-20, dapps

Let's say I have a dApp with multiple users. This app works with an ER20 token that acts like credits for the user. I want the token in each user's wallet to be minted on a daily basis:

1. How do I mint the wallet with new tokens?
2. How do I trigger this minting each 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can implement a mint function in your contract to mint the tokens to the desired address or list of addresses.
2. You can try this approach to schedule function calls: [Can you call a contract function via a cron job?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23289/can-you-call-a-contract-function-via-a-cron-job)