# Best way to schedule function calls

Tags: solidity

I'm working on an app the needs to run a function by schedule (every week for example). I've been trying to use Ethereum Alarm Clock but it seems outdated.

Are there any alternatives or a way to just build it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some steps to consider, I suggest to take look at this similar question: [Can you call a contract function via a cron job?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23289/can-you-call-a-contract-function-via-a-cron-job)